# How to change only month, year and date in Calendar object without changing the hours, mins and seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I want to set `now` to have the current time fields (hours, minutes and seconds) but I want to set the year to 1970 January 1st. The code below doesnt do that using the [set(int year, int month, int date)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) command. The Year, Month and date remains on the current (i.e. today's) date.

```java
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 01);
```

How to change the year, month and date field only?

Comment: now.getTime().toString(); gave me result: "Thu Jan 01 03:55:14 CET 1970". Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Is your local time right now (when you ran the command) 3:55am?

Comment: Yes. My timezone is GMT+1 so it was 3:55am when code was executed

Comment: Can you show me the log output demonstrating the value remains the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
```

Comment: The `'time` field in `cal` stays at 1479526935691 (which is Fri Nov 18 2016 21:42:15) which is what is confusing me: http://imgur.com/a/saUDf

Comment: Never mind, when I use `gettimeinmillis()` on the Calendar object, it works. So I will mark this as answer.